# Java: How to make a variable's value change outside a switch? (just read the post)

Tags: java, switch-statement

EDIT: Full Code for people who need it: https://hastebin.com/tovazutuni.cs

ok so im working on a big burger shop challenge, but to keep it simple, here is a similair problem im facing:

```
public class Burger {

private double priceWithAdditions = 5.00;
private double price = 5.00;
private String addition1;
private double addition1Price;

switch(burgersAdditionScanner()){
   case "mayo": 

       this.addition1 = "Mayo";
       this.addition1Price = 0.40;
       this.priceWithAdditions += this.addition1Price;
       System.out.println("Added Additions " + this.addition1 + " for the price of $" +this.addition1Price);

           break;

default: System.out.println("Get Out");
```

Later down in the code, I have a method to print the receipt, but the values of the variables changed inside the switch do not update outside of it:

```
public void Receipt() {

    System.out.println("You Bought " + this.name + " burger for the price of $" + this.price + " with the following \nAdditions:");

    if(this.addition1 != null ) {

        System.out.println("Addition " + this.addition1 + " for $" + this.addition1Price);

    }


System.out.println("The final price is " + this.priceWithAdditions); }
```

Considering the values of addition1 and priceWithAdditions didnt change in the case, addition 1 is null and priceWithAdditions is still 5.00 instead of 5.40. Does anyone know how to make the values of these variables update ourside of the switch. If you can help me Id really appreciate it, please and thank you

Console Output: (There's a scanner so I can type my choices)

```
    add addition 1

Choose Addition 1
Lettuce  -  $0.50 
Cheese  -   $1.00 
Ketchup  -  $0.20 
Mayo  -   $0.40

mayo

Added Addition Mayonaise for the price of $0.4

Add Additions or none
Add Addition 1 
Add Addition 2 
Add Adition 3 
Add Adition 4 
Receipt

receipt

You Bought Amer's Booty burger for the price of $5.0 with the following 
Additions:
The final price is 5.0
Get Out
```

Comment: You should format your code

Comment: You don't seem to actually add any of your additions to `this.priceWithAdditions`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you look in case "mayo", I wrote this.priceWithAdditions += this.addition1Price; (which  is basically the same as this.priceWith Additions = this.priceWithAdditions + this.addition1Price) The addition1Price is 0.40, so it shoud print out 5.40 not 5.00, but It keeps going back to 5.00

Comment: Is your switch statement inside a function? Share that full function. And read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Steephen No it's just a class, the actual code includes 4 classes and 200+ lines of code, it was too much to post for a small question like this. Im simply asking how I can change the value of a variable inside a switch

Comment: Where are you calling `Receipt()`? More importantly, what instance of `Burger` are you calling it on?

Comment: The bug isn't in your switch. Show your full code please.

Comment: @Vikram Receipt is in class Burger, receipt is being called from a method located in another class called Restaurant, and that method in class restaurant is being called from the main class. And sorry, i dont understand your question: what instance of Burger are you calling it on? (im still relatively new to Java)

Comment: Uploading full code to Hastebin, one min please

Comment: Here is the code, apologies if it's unorganized and is inefficient, Im still new to Java:

https://hastebin.com/tovazutuni.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `Receipt()` on the wrong instance of `Burger`. For all calls to `Receipt()` (that I'm seeing), you are calling it on a new instance of a `Burger`, like so:

```
case "receipt": 
    HealthyBurger burgerReceipt = new HealthyBurger();
    burgerReceipt.Receipt();
```

`burgerReceipt` is a new instance of a `HealthyBurger`, and not the one that you called any of your addition operators on. As such, it will contain the default values of your `HealthyBurger`. You can fix this, by calling `Receipt` on the same instance of `HealthyBurger` that was mutated. For example:

```
HealthyBurger burger = new HealthyBurger()
burger.addAddition6()
burger.Receipt()
```

Your code is a bit too messy for me to give you an exact solution to your problem, but you are creating new instances of `Burger` all over the place, in a `Restaurant` class which also happens to be a `Burger` itself. I think if you take the time to read up on basic inheritance/object oriented principles, you should be able to simplify your code significantly.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. Im a slow learner but I want to learn, would you recommend any courses or videos to improve my understanding of OOP or inheritance?

Comment: @WackyBoss I'm glad that helped! Unfortunately it's been so long since I started with Java, I don't have any recommendations for you. There are a ton of resources out there though, and I'm sure most are very good.

Comment: Requests for recommendations are Off-Topic.